# change $scope value in controller dose not reflect in view

Tags: angularjs

I try to implement register functionality in my web app,
    Right now I can post date to my sever and get response with user data,
    my logic is after get response from sever, my app go to app.loggedin state,
   and I configured using ui-router as follow:

```
    .state('app.loggedin',{
      url:'',
      views: {  
          'header@':{  // specify the view need to change
                  templateUrl:'header.html'
                      }  ,

           'content@':{  // specify the view need to change
                 templateUrl:'main.html'
                      }  

        }
    }),
```

I want the nav bar to show user's username after logged in, I update $scope.user in my controller, 
and  I did like this:

```
 $scope.user
      UserFactory.register(username,password,function(err,result){
                                  if (err) {
                                    // do something

                                  }


                                    $state.go('app.loggedin',{reload :true});
                                    $scope.user=result.user;
                                    console.log($scope.user);


                          });
```

and my html:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav  color-white navbar-right" ng-controller="UserController">
  <li ng-if="!user"><a ui-sref="app.signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> signup</a></li>
  <li ng-if="!user"><a ui-sref="app.login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> login</a></li>
  <li ng-if="user">
    <a ui-sref="app.signup"> {{user.username}}</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

the console can print the user correctly, but scope.user is not updated in my view, can it is still null, and so cannot show user's username.
if I change ng-if="!user" to ng-if="user", the sign up does not show.
what wrong is here, I have been stuck here for couple hours,
Please help.
Thanks,
and also is it the right way to manipulate DOM?
I am very new to Angular, and I see someone use Directive to manipulate DOM,
any sugesstion?

add :
    service('UserFactory',['SharedDataFactory','$http','baseURL',
            function(SharedDataFactory,$http,baseURL){

```
            this.register = function(username,password,callback){
                $http.post(baseURL+'user/register',
                    {username:username,password:password}).then(
                    function(response){
                          callback(null,response.data);
                    },
                    function(response){
                    callback(response.data,null);
                    }
                    );               
            };     
    }])
```

Comment: Did you try `$scope.$apply()` after setting the `$scope.user`?

Comment: I think you may need to show something of `UserFactory.register`. You're using a callback instead of a promise so how is that callback being triggered?

Comment: @Duncan Probably OP uses it in a way the dirty checking is not performed after callback invocation.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin, yes but unless he posts the relevant code we're just guessing.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar, no you don't. Any values in a parent scope are also available in the child scope (unless hidden by another variable with the same name, or unless the child is an isolated scope).

Comment: @gauravbhavsar, your link points to a question asking about assigning to a value in a child scope. That is totally different to the case here which is just accessing the value.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin   no, I did not. I will look up what $apply for.

Comment: @Duncan just added the code.

Comment: the console can print the $scope.user correctly as an object, but scope.user is not updated in my view, this is why  is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that on successful login you are transitioning to another state:

```
$state.go('app.loggedin',{reload :true});
$scope.user=result.user;
console.log($scope.user);
```

The `$state.go` will load a new state (`reload:true` will force it to be a brand new state even if it is the same as the current one). Controllers and associated scopes don't get re-used, so you will have a brand new `UserController` instance after the state transition, but your executing code still refers to the old (shortly to be destroyed) `$scope`.

The solution to this is to push the user details down into a service as services are always singletons. You already have a service, so you can store the details there.

So in UserController, something like:

```
$scope.user = UserFactory.user;
```

And UserFactory something like:

```
service('UserFactory',['SharedDataFactory','$http','baseURL',
     function(SharedDataFactory,$http,baseURL){
        var self = this;
        this.user = {};
        this.register = function(username,password){
            return $http.post(baseURL+'user/register',
                {username:username,password:password}).then(
                angular.copy(response.data, self.user);
                return self.user;
                });               
        };     
}])
```

Note the service updates the user object rather than replacing it. This means the changed attributes will be visible through the `$scope.user` reference as well. Also I changed your function to return a promise rather than using a callback as that will simplify further handling of the response.

Then you can just call the registration function from the register controller:

```
  UserFactory.register(username,password)
  .catch(function(err){
      // do something
  })
  .then(function(user) {
       $state.go('app.loggedin',{reload :true});
       console.log('Logged in', user);
  });
```

Comment: Thank so much, solved all my concerns about data communicating in service and controller.  I always wasnt sure the execution flow  of angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav  color-white navbar-right" ng-controller="UserController">
 <li ng-if="!user"><a ui-sref="app.signup">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon- user"></span> signup</a></li>
 <li ng-if="!user"><a ui-sref="app.login">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> login</a></li>
 <li ng-if="user">
   <a ui-sref="app.signup"> {{user}}</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Use user instead of user.username

Comment: this does not change much, the problem is user not get updated in view