# Changing scope value in $watch does not reflect in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML

```
 <nav-Header></nav-Header>
 <div ng-controller="loginController">
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Search for a docType"
            typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)"
            ng-model="selected" /> <span class="input-group-addon"
            ng-click="alert()"> <i
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i>
        </span>
    </div>

    sme= {{sme}}
</div>
```

Controller - Making nested REST calls to backend

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var ezControllers = angular.module('login.controller', ['com.doc.ui.components.message.services',
    'com.doc.ui.components.message.constants'
  ]);

  ezControllers.controller('loginController', [
    '$state',
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    '$window',
    'messageService',
    'messageCodesConstant',
    '$http',
    '$location',
    '$timeout',
    '$uibModal',
    '$interval',
    '$rootScope',
    'com.doc.ui.loginService',
    'com.doc.ui.dropdownService',
    function($state, $scope, $log, $window, messageService,
      messageCodesConstant, $http, $location, $timeout,
      $uibModal, $interval, $rootScope, loginService, dropdownService) {

      var self = this;

      // flag to keep track of service operation
      this.callInProgress = false;
      $scope.docList = null;

      $scope.something = null;

      // $scope.docList = "hi there";
      $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
      /**
       * Authenticate the user
       */
      var call = $scope.authenticate = function(
        inUserName, inUserPassword) {



        // authenticate the user using service, and
        // if all good,
        // then forward to the home page
        self.callInProgress = true;
        loginService.authenticate(inUserName,
            inUserPassword)
          .then(
            // on successful
            // authentication
            function(userProfile) {




              dropdownService.getDocTypeList().then(
                // on successful
                // authentication
                function(docTypeList) {

                  // go to Search page
                  // directly


                  $log.log('docTypeList in controller:' + angular
                    .toJson(docTypeList.recordsList, true));

                  angular.forEach(docTypeList.recordsList, function(docType) {
                    console.log(docType.name);


                  })

                  // $scope.docList=docTypeList.recordsList;
                  $log.log('scope.docList:' + docTypeList.recordsList[0].name);

                  //setting new value
                  $scope.something = 'updated valuee';


                  $scope.$watch('something', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                    $log.log('newvalue: ' + newVal + ':oldval:' + oldVal);
                    $scope.sme = newVal;

                  });

                  $state
                    .go('home');

                },
                // on getting error
                function(errorMsg) {
                  $log
                    .error('Error in userlogin controller: ' + errorMsg);
                  messageService
                    .error(
                      messageCodesConstant.LOGIN_FAILURE,
                      "doc type list service Failure! Please try again. Error: " + errorMsg);
                },
                // update from service -
                // optional
                function(update) {
                  $log
                    .log('Update in userlogin controller: ' + update);
                }).finally(function() {
                $log.log('Service call to authenticate user ended.');
                self.callInProgress = false;
              });





            },
            // on getting error
            function(errorMessage) {
              $log
                .error('Error in userlogin controller: ' + errorMessage);
              messageService
                .error(
                  messageCodesConstant.LOGIN_FAILURE,
                  "Login Failure! Please try again. Error: " + errorMessage);
            },
            // update from service -
            // optional
            function(update) {
              $log
                .log('Update in userlogin controller: ' + update);
            }).finally(function() {
            $log.log('Service call to authenticate user ended.');
            self.callInProgress = false;
          });

      };



    }
  ]);


})();
```

When $scope.something changes, I am assigning the new value to $scope.sme (refer to watch method). $scope.sme in html does not have any value.However, when I log the values, I am seeing the updated value there. I came across this post, but dint understand how it could be applied to my case - [change $scope value in controller dose not reflect in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598001/change-scope-value-in-controller-dose-not-reflect-in-view)

Comment: You typically do not want to attach your $watches in the callback of a callback. You might also look into how to chain promises so that you don't have this level of nesting. Also look into how to create a [mcve]. It may very well help you find where the problem is.

Comment: I understand it is better to reduce the complexity of the code. however, I am looking for a quick fix.